# Angular, TypeScript, tslint ... одинарные кавычки вместо двойных?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular4, visual-studio-code, tslint

Использую **VS Code**, стоит расширение **tslint**. Весьма требовательное, но в целом - всё подсказывает верно. Но я не понимаю момента с кавычками.

Где бы я не писал двойные кавычки в .ts файлах - он всюду мне кричит о том, что это грубая ошибка и что нужно их заменять на одинарные. С чего это вдруг? Где стандарт насчёт этого? Зачем нужны именно одинарные кавычки?

[image: tslint]